# (iOS MPMusicPlayerNotification) how to receive notification when app is in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, background, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm using `[MPMusicPlayerController ipodMusicPlayer]` to play songs in my application

so that the song experience doesn't get interrupted even if the app goes to the background.

I've registered `MPMusicPlayerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification` in my app delegate,

so that whenever the music changes I can stop the player for a while, do something, and

then re-play it again.

The problem is, I need to receive the notification even when the app is in the background

and my app is the only application that's using the `ipodMusicPlayer`. (that is, default music app isn't open).

I've been playing around with `applicationDidEnterBackground`, but I just can't get it to work.

How should I achieve this?

Thank You in advance

Comment: You need to set your app for background mode to App plays audio

Comment: I already did but that doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this.

Declare all your notification receivers in your app delegate, along with

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
```

Then, initialize a CLLocationManager object and start receiving location changes.

This way, your app will not be suspended even if it goes to the background,

and your appdelegate will keep receiving playbacknotifications.

However, if will only work with applications using GPS features.

Comment: is this Apple approval compliant do you think ?

Comment: As of the application that I'm building, I do need to get the GPS coordinates of my users. I'm not sure if Apple will approve of using GPS just to enable notification receiving in the background.